# Teradata : join index not be used when querying primary index column of join index table

Tags: indexing, teradata

I create a join index for table employee,

```
CREATE JOIN INDEX a.EMP_JI  AS
SELECT a.employee_number,
       a.department_number ,
       a.last_name,          
       a.manager_employee_number
       FROM customerservice.employee a
       PRIMARY INDEX ( last_name );
```

and then I query the table customerservice.employee like this:

```
explain sel * from customerservice.employee where last_name = 'Brown';
```

the result is:

Explanation

1. First, we lock a distinct customerservice."pseudo table" for read on a RowHash to prevent global deadlock for customerservice.employee.
2. Next, we lock customerservice.employee for read
3. We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from customerservice.employee by way of an all-rows scan with a condition of ("customerservice.employee.last_name = 'Brown '") into Spool 1 (group_amps), which is built locally on the AMPs. The size of Spool 1 is estimated with no confidence to be 2 rows (286 bytes). The estimated time for this step is 0.07 seconds.
4. Finally, we send out an END TRANSACTION step to all AMPs involved in processing the request.

-> The contents of Spool 1 are sent back to the user as the result of statement 1. The total estimated time is 0.07 seconds.

From the result of Explain, join index emp_ji not used, a little confused,

Comment: #1: There are no statistics on the JI #2: As you `select *` there must be a join back to the base table and the table is just too small (26 rows), all rows fit in a single datablock per AMP, thus reading the base table is more efficient.

Comment: after i run this : collect stats on customerservice.emp_ji column last_name; and then run explain again, now it query directly from join index, thanks a lot,